# 2008 Pontiac Grand Prix Fails to Start and Electronics Go Awry

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, pontiac, starter

My mother-in-law drove over this morning to pick up my wife, and when they tried to leave the car wouldn't start.  Not only that; the horn honked, the wipers started, the trunk popped open, and the brights turned on.  It did not start.

Is this a grounding problem, or is there some simpler solution?  If it's a grounding problem, how do I locate it?

Comment: Does "did not start" mean that the ignition didn't even cause the starter motor to rotate?  Or did the starter motor turn but the engine never reached idle?

Comment: "Weirdness" stinks of a battery failure, but we need more information. Have you attempted to jump or bump start the vehicle?

Comment: Some more to help diagnose the problem: If you turn on the interior lights and the headlights, do the lights dim when you try to start the car or do they stay the same?

Comment: I don't notice any dimming, but then again, the brights are coming on as soon as the key turns.  I don't hear the starter turning at all.  Can't jump or bump it at the moment.

Comment: Happened to me tonight with wide and New born in the car. Thanks for the info. Now to try to find out how to reset the computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computer reset fixed the problem.  I find this somewhat disconcerting that the computer could execute such ridiculous commands based off a turned key.

Comment: Congrats and that's really odd.  If it happens again, please come back and add to this saga: if it can happen to you, it's happening to someone else who's also going to be terribly frustrated.